# Error building joe / jmacs editor on MacOS 13.5.2

Tags: c, macos

This is not so much a question as something I ran into, and want to share the solution with the community.

I love the jmacs editor from Joe's Own Editor. There is no native Mac package available, so for use on a Mac, one needs to compile from source. Here's how:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --sysconfdir=/etc
sudo vi joe/tty.c
```

Add this line near top:

```
#include <util.h>
```

then

```
sudo LC_ALL=C make install
```

Avoiding this build error:

> tty.c:975:6: error: call to undeclared function 'openpty'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>
> ```
>    if (openpty(ptyfd, ttyfd, name, NULL, NULL) == 0) {
>        ^
> ```
>
> tty.c:975:6: note: did you mean 'openat'?
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/fcntl.h:600:9: note: 'openat' declared here
>
> ```
> int     openat(int, const char *, int, ...) __DARWIN_NOCANCEL(openat) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_10, __IPHONE_8_0);
>         ^
> ```
>
> tty.c:1221:6: error: call to undeclared function 'login_tty'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>
> ```
>                                    login_tty(1);
> ```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you generally *do not* want to run `configure` (or `make`) using `sudo`. You should only require privileges when *installing* the software (`sudo make install`).

Comment: Hmm you are right. Thanks for pointing this out! I tested it; works without sudo for `configure`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and "[answer]". Yes, you are allowed to answer your own question... I think it fits better to this Q&A site if you [edit] your question and separate question (make sure you have at least one question mark) and answer.

Comment: please revise to fit the question-answer pattern. move the answer part into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
sudo make install
```

, first run

```
sudo make clean
```

to clean up, then run these 3 commands:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I wasn't asking for help ... I was posting the tested solution as a question. Thanks for your reply however!

Comment: you dont post solutions as questions, you ask a question and then post the answer as an answer